# Escaping the '@' Symbol in a dynamic query called through C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I've got a simple console app at the moment that calls a stored procedure with a few parameters and creates a dynamic query and executes it. However, in the dynamic query i'll need to pass a value that contains the '@' symbol. For example in the @Query parameter I need to pass a value that contains the '@' symbol. This is dynamic so the value may not contain this in the future:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "STORED PROCEDURE";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Query", Value = "@ID, A, B, C", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Database", Value = "XXXX", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Server", Value = "YYYY", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
ocmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@TableName", Value = "TESTTABLE", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
....
....
....
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then on the Sql Server end, I piece these parameters together so that it looks as such:

```
SET @SQLQuery  = 'INSERT INTO ' + convert(varchar(500),@TableName)  + ' EXEC SOME_OTHER_STORED_PROC ' 
                    + convert(varchar(500),@Query) + ', ' 
                    + convert(varchar(500),@Database) + ', ' 
                    + convert(varchar(500),@Server) 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Every time I run this I get the following error **Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".**

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: the error makes sense, you are setting @Query=@ID.   What are you thinking @ID would be?  You have to give an actual value or reference an existing variable.

Comment: Seems you need quotes around all the parameters. There'd better be no dynamic typing here. So the Q becomes: how to escape `'` in SQL text.

Comment: Hi T, That is just the type of parameter the stored procedure (the 'SOME_OTHER_STORED_PROCEDURE') needs (I didn't write it, it was written by a third party). Anyway to escape it?

Comment: FWIW, your stored proc opens you up to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks, Henk's response was helpful for me to pinpoint and fix the issue so i will reward the answer to him. Jim, I'm aware that it is basically set up for SQL injection attacks but this is an internal, company use-only app used for overnight extracts (it isnt even run by a human!). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that problem is the @ character. As you have defined the query, the @ID is considered as parameter, which is not defined anywhere. 
If the expression

> @ID, A, B, C

means the value of a parameter for the procedure EXEC SOME_OTHER_STORED_PROC, then declare the parameter like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Query", Value = "'@ID, A, B, C'", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
```